# Kth element in an unordered list, using k order statistic - Time complexity O(n)?

Tags: algorithm

Can some one tell me how Randomized select algorithm gives average case time complexity of O(n)? I see that it will have the best case O(n) if the randomly selected pivot (during 1st pass) is the kth element in the list. But how can this be average case? we cant guarantee that every time we run the algorithm we will hit the correct one in the first pass itself rt?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After the first pass you know which "half" the k'th element will be in. Now you repeat the process on that "half", etc.

So, in the average case in the first iteration you do n steps, in the second n/2 steps, then n/4 steps and so on. As a back of the envelope calculation, assume n = 2**k. The total number of steps would be

```
2**k + 2**k/2 + 2**k/4 + ... = 2**k + 2**(k-1) + 2**(k-2) + ... + 2 + 1 
                             = 2**(k+1) - 1 
                             = 2n - 1
```

So, the algorithm is O(2n - 1) = O(n).

Answer (score 4):

After random position is selected and current range is partitioned we know whether k-th element is on the left side or on the right side. Then we recourse algorithm on one side. So we have complexity on average T(n) = n + T(n/2), (n for partitioning). Thus we have O(n) on average